# How can I get difference between two dates format like HH:MI:SS?

Tags: oracle

In oracle Query How can I get difference between two dates format like HH:MI:SS?

There are two dates with timestamp format like `'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS'` 
How can I get difference between these two dates like `HH:MI:SS`?

Example:

```
Date1= '15/11/2015 11:19:58'
Date2= '14/11/2015 10:20:58'


Output:25:01:00 (HH:MI:SS)
```

I tried below query

```
select to_char(('15/11/2015 11:19:58'-'14/11/2015 10:20:58'),'HH24:MI:SS') 
from dual;
```

I’m getting below output:

```
+000000001 01:01:000
```

But I want this format `25:01:00 (HH:MI:SS)`

Comment: Duplicate of [Oracle: Calculate time difference in HH:MM:SS between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20867220/oracle-calculate-time-difference-in-hhmmss-between-2-dates)

Comment: Your query is invalid as you're trying to subtract string not dates; and the output you showed is an interval, suggesting you've subtracted two timestamps. not dates? [This might help?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45601629/266304)